# How to calculate pixel size as a zoom percentage

Tags: javascript, math, width, zooming, percentage

I have the following situation and whilst I am fine with the coding, I am struggling with the maths lol.

I have a div that is 500 pixels wide.  Jquery is loaded.

I am going to check the browser width and store it in a javascript variable called bwidth.

If bwidth is less than 500px (the width of the div) then I want to resize the div using css zoom (for various reasons including the content of the div).

All of this is easy to do code wise but what I am trying to work out is the algo for calculating what the zoom percentage should be to make the 500px width div actually fit  inside a browser window that is bwdith pixels wide.

I am not worried about height.

So, lets say that bwidth is 250px - I know that I need a 50% zoom but only because I know that 250 is half of 500 lol!  How do I calculate that 50% programmatically.

What if bwidth is 325px ?  How do I calculate the correct zoom ?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Apologies for my moment of mathematical stupidity - answered my own question below - you can tell I am working to a deadline here LOL!

Comment: try like this var zoom=100/(500/bwidth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
var zoom=100/(500/bwidth)
```

for Example

```
<script>

var zoom=100/(500/bwidth)
console.log(zoom+"%")

</script>
```